# EasyAdmin 2.0.* and Symfony 3.4 composer errors

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony-3.4, php-7.1, easyadmin

I am trying to install EasyAdminBundle 2.0.* version on my Symfony 3.4, but composer shows conflicts. I have tried to check with packagist where would be a problem, but I haven't found any tip. Can somebody help in reading composer error ? Is it possible to install EasyAdmin 2.* on Symfony 3.4 ? 
My php version is 7.1.14.

Thank you in advance.
Tomas

```html
 Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.4.21
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.21
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.20
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.19
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.18
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.17
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.16
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.15
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.14
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.13
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.12
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.11
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.10
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.9
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.8
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.1
    - easycorp/easyadmin-bundle v2.0.0 requires symfony/expression-language ^4.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/expression-language[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.2].
    - easycorp/easyadmin-bundle v2.0.1 requires symfony/expression-language ^4.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/expression-language[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.2].
    - easycorp/easyadmin-bundle v2.0.2 requires symfony/expression-language ^4.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/expression-language[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.2].
    - don't install symfony/expression-language v4.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/expression-language v4.1.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/expression-language v4.1.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/expression-language v4.1.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/expression-language v4.1.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/expression-language v4.1.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/expression-language v4.1.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/expression-language v4.1.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/expression-language v4.1.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/expression-language v4.1.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/expression-language v4.1.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/expression-language v4.2.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/expression-language v4.2.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - don't install symfony/expression-language v4.2.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 3.4.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.2, v3.4.20, v3.4.21, v3.4.3, v3.4.4, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9].
    - Installation request for easycorp/easyadmin-bundle ^2.0 -> satisfiable by easycorp/easyadmin-bundle[v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.2].
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `composer.lock` or / and `/vendor`? It helps in similar cases

Comment: Sometime it helps, but not in this case unfortunately. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

EasyAdminBundle 2.0 requires symfony 4.1 So upgrade symfony, or use EasyAdminBundle 1.17.19 (newest from 1.x branch)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Symfony/doctrine-bridge 4.1 means it is for symfony 4.1 right ? Is this a version naming convention or just accidental convergence ? Btw. I have choosen sf 3.4 because of lts.

Comment: @tomas Yes `symfony/doctrine-bridge 4.1` means that it's a package from symfony 4.1

Comment: for me worked installing easyAdminBundle on version 1.17.21. Thanks!